# error in json parser in eclipse

Tags: php, android, json, web-applications

I am making a andriod app which performs CRUD operations on a localhost php database
here is my code and the log cat. please help to fix the errors

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and the Log Cat is

```
03-12 12:43:57.924: W/KeyCharacterMap(278): No keyboard for id 0
03-12 12:43:57.924: W/KeyCharacterMap(278): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-12 12:44:15.164: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2568 objects / 144968 bytes in 197ms
03-12 12:44:19.394: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 425 objects / 203056 bytes in 44ms
03-12 12:44:23.594: W/System.err(278): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
03-12 12:44:23.594: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:410)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-12 12:44:23.624: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:95)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-12 12:44:23.634: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-12 12:44:23.645: W/System.err(278):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-12 12:44:23.645: E/Buffer Error(278): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 12:44:23.645: E/JSON Parser(278): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-12 12:44:23.645: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:99)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-12 12:44:23.664: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 4 more
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278): Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f60fc0 that was originally added here
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f60fc0 that was originally added here
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:76)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:56)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-12 12:44:24.354: E/WindowManager(278):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please assist to solve the errors

Comment: post your `Asynctask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the String with `equals()` method or `equalsIgnoreCase()`

`==` check there the object of the reference are same

change `if(method == "GET")` with `if(method.equals("GET"))`

Comment: @user3312672 it's ok glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

String comparison is a common programming task and Java provides several way to compare two String in Java. String is a special class in Java, String is immutable.

Here are four examples of comparing String in Java
1) String comparison using equals method
2) String comparison using equalsIgnoreCase method
3) String comparison using compareTo method
4) String comparison using compareToIgnoreCase method

**Compare two String using equals method in Java**

String comparison example - compare two strings using equalsequals()method compare two Strings for content equality. So if two string contains same letters, in same order and in same case they will be equals by equals() method. equals() method is defined in Object class and String class overrides that for character based comparison.

**Compare String using equalsIgnoreCase method in Java**

equalsIgnoreCase is more liberal than equals and compare two strings ignoring there case. So if two String contains same characters and in same order despite of there case e.g. lower case, upper case, Capital case or Camel case they will be equal by equalsIgnoreCase.

**Comparing String using compareTo**

compareTo are actual comparison method unlike equals()and equalsIgnoreCase() and tell us whether two Strings are lexicographically equal, precedes or follows each other. if you want to sort Strings lexicographically compareTo() method is used. this is also called natural order of String.   returns zero if two Strings are same, less than zero if calling string comes before argument string and greater than zero if calling string comes later than argument string as shown in example below. See things to remember while overriding compareTo method in Java for more detail on compareTo method.

**Compare String using compareToIgnoreCase**

Similar to compareTo() method with ignoring case like equalsIgnoreCase() and return same values as returned by compareTo during String comparison.

**Don't use "==" for String comparison**

Many Java programmer makes mistake of using "==" for string comparison. "==" just check if two reference variable are pointing two same object in Java heap and since String is immutable in Java and maintained in String pool two String literal refer same String object which gives sense that "==" can be used to compare string which is incorrect. always use equals() method for equality check and compareTo method for actual string comparison.

Another way of comparing String is writing custom Comparator in Java. write your comparison logic in compare() method and than you can use that logic to compare two strings.